# log in from sql to c# uppercase

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a login system wherein employee will access through it. The data is coming from SQL Server
and the problem is whenever I input a username that is in uppercase but the data in database is not in uppercase. Still I can access... here is the code tnx

```
sum.connect.Open();
  try
        {
            if (!(txtBoxUN.Text == string.Empty))
            {
                if (!(txtboxPW.Text == string.Empty))
                {
                    //String query = "select COUNT(*) from LogIn where LI_UserName = '" + txtBoxUN.Text + "'";
                    String query = "select * from LogIn where LI_UserName = '" + txtBoxUN.Text + "' and LI_PWord = '" + txtboxPW.Text + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sum.connect);


                    sum.connect.Open();
                    dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int count = 0;
                    while (dbr.Read())
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Log In Success...", "Log On Information...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);  //for sucsseful login
                        PyrllMdl prll = new PyrllMdl();
                        this.Hide();
                        prll.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName and/or Password...", "Log On Information...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        txtBoxUN.Text = "";
                        txtboxPW.Text = "";
                        txtBoxUN.Focus();
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Password...", "Log On Information...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    txtboxPW.Focus();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter UserName...", "Log On Information...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtBoxUN.Focus();
            }
            sum.connect.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);

        }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Can you please expand on the problem you are having ?

Comment: for example i have a usename Admin in database and what i type in textbox is ADMIN....still it goes

Comment: @KevinSabila check the solution which I gave you with COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as.

Comment: Is logging in such a difficult problem that we have to have dozens of these questions every day?

Comment: Also, don't store passwords in plaintext. Don't do any of this really.

Comment: @siride probably for guys which just starting and don't have good research skills is a problem.

Comment: @mybirthname: it is a problem, and we keep coddling them. Over and over and over again.

Comment: @siride You can just move to the next question.  Login is where a lot of people start and so we see a lot of rookie questions.

Comment: By convention, usernames are **not** supposed to be case sensitive. `User` and `user` are the same. Passwords **are** supposed to be case sensitive. In any case, don't try to write your own authentication code. It's so easy to write something the seems to work, but is flawed in subtle ways that results in your app getting hacked six months later. Always lean as much as possible on the authentication apis provided to you by your platform of choice.

Comment: Also: -1 until we see some indication that you've acknowledged the **HUGE** sql injection issue in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should use SqlParameters to prevent from SQL Injection. Also parameters give the possibility to the sql server to cache queries. After that you need to write your query like this, to check about difference between **upper case and lower case**.

The *trick* is done by `COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as`

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM LogIn where LI_UserName=@UserName COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as AND LI_PWord = @Password COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sum.connect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@UserName, txtBoxUN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Password, txtboxPW.Text);
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

The default collation for SQL is case insenstive - SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

See http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm for serveral ways of doing a case sensitive `select`.

```
var query = @"select * FROM LogIn 
              where LI_UserName = @username COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
                and LI_PWord = @password COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as":

var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sum.connect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtBoxUN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtboxPW.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a case sensitive collation

[Selecting a SQL Server Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx)

[SQL Server Collation Name (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
"select * from LogIn where LI_UserName = '" + txtBoxUN.Text + "' and LI_PWord = '" + 
     txtboxPW.Text + "' " + "collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1250_CS_AS";
```

And you should use a parametrized query. I was just answering the question as stated.

Comment: This is more a comment.

Comment: @Piyush That is not a link only answer.  See the select statement.